# Changing the default size of the docstring hover tooltip in Eclipse PyDev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

How can I change the default size of the docstring pop-up / hover tooltip in Eclipse PyDev?

By default it is quite small, e.g.:

[image]

(the "docstring pop-up" is the pop-up with the yellow background)

I am aware that I can change its dimension using the bottom right draggable object but the dimension change doesn't apply next time a docstring pop-up   appears:

[image]

Comment: That's not configurable (I believe it's always fit to the contents, so, not sure if it'd actually be better with a pre-defined size).

Comment: @FabioZadrozny: Thank you, you are welcome to convert your comment into an answer :-)